# INSERT data based on IF EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, insert

I'm building a system update feature for a client of mine, the client drags and drops a xls sheet (export form SAP) and that query basically `TRUNCATES` the existing "project data" in the `import_table` and inserts all project data from the xls, now that works fine, but what I need help with is writing a stored procedure that selects the `project_number` from the `import_table` and checks if that `project_number` already exists in the `project_table`, and if it doesn't exist then INSERT the new project data from `import_table` by `project_number`.

So far what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_projects` ()
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_projects`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `permit`.`project2`(project,description,mat,city,stat,own,est_start,est_end,constr_start,constr_end,constr_cnf,plan_order,div_code,div_long,constr_total_plan,constr_total_act)
    SELECT OrderNo,OrderDescription,mat,MainWorkCtr,OrdUsrStatus,JobOwner,ESTStartDate,ESTEndDate,ConstrStartDate,ConstrEndDate,ConstrCNFDate,PlanningOrder,division,division_long,cons_total_plan_hrs,cons_total_act_hrs
    FROM `permit`.`wrm100_raw` i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `permit`.`project2` pt WHERE i.OrderNo = pt.project)
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you can do the check using a `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_projects`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `db`.`project_table` (project_table columns...) 
        SELECT import_table columns...
        FROM db.import_table i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM db.project_table pt
                          WHERE i.project_number = pt.project_number
                         )
END;
```

If the concern is duplicated `project_number`s, then you should define a unique constraint/index and let the database validate the data.

Comment: sorry for the delay those columns took forever to plug in.  I ran it and it gave me an error on the last line. I updated the main thread to show the actual values.